# Await an Anonymous Type

Tags: .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, controller, async-await

In an ASP.NET Core WebApi Controller, I try to return a json `{ payload: myArray }`

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetEntriesPaged(int? page, int pageSize = 10) {
    ...
    return Ok( await new { payload = query.ToListAsync() }); }
```

> Error CS1061  ' payload>' does not contain
>   a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method
>   'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type ' payload>' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

PS. The whole function to better understanding

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetEntriesPaged(int? sourceId, string filter, int? pageIndex, int pageSize = DEFAULT_PAGESIZE, string sortOrder = Order.DESC) {

    IQueryable<Entry> query = _db.Entries;
    // 0. Filter by sourceId 
    if (sourceId.HasValue) {
        query = query.Where(e => e.SourceId == sourceId.Value);
    }

    // 1. Filter by message or subject or from or to
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter)) {
        query = query.Where(e => e.Message.Contains(filter) || e.Subject.Contains(filter) || e.From.Contains(filter) || e.To.Contains(filter));
    }

    // 2. Order by Date         
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sortOrder) || sortOrder.ToLower() != Order.ASC) { sortOrder = Order.DESC; }
    sortOrder = sortOrder.ToLower();
    if (sortOrder == Order.ASC) {
        query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Date);
    }
    else {
        query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
    }

    // 3. Get paged elements (Skip & Take)
    if (pageIndex.HasValue) {
        if (pageIndex < 0) { pageIndex = 0; }
        if (pageSize < 1) { pageSize = 1; }
        int take = pageSize;
        int skip = (pageIndex.Value * pageSize);

        var paginationMetadata = new {
            totalCount = query.Count(),
            pageSize = pageSize,
            currentPage = pageIndex
        };

        Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationMetadata));
        query = query.Skip(skip).Take(take);
    }

    return Ok( await new { payload = query.ToListAsync() });
}
```

Comment: I updated to use ToListAsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await the `ToListAsync`:

```
return Ok( new { payload = await query.ToListAsync() });
```